# Using focus and blur to show and hide a DIV in an unordered list

Tags: jquery, focus, show-hide, blur

I am using [Fred LeBlancs roundabout plugin](http://fredhq.com/projects/roundabout) and I have incorporated a lightbox to the "active"  central image only ( why I "addClass" .active). I also want to show a hidden div with caption text when the image is the active one. I have succeeded with the lightbox but all my captions hide or show when the central image is focused and I of course just need the active one. Need a bit of help to show just the one caption.

```
<li><a href="slide.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto" title="Slide">
 <img src="slide_thumb.jpg" alt="Slide" /></a>
 <div class="caption" style="display:none">Slide Caption</div>
</li>
```

My code:

```
$('ul.rbt li').focus(function() {
  $('a').addClass('active');
  $('.caption').show()
});
$('ul.rbt li').blur(function() {
  $('a').removeClass('active');
  $('.caption').hide()
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
$('ul.rbt li').focus(function() {
    $(this).find('a').addClass('active');
    $(this).find('.caption').show()
});
$('ul.rbt li').blur(function() {
    $('a').removeClass('active');
    $('.caption').hide()
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use this if you are thinking of having the caption shown everytime a user focuses on the image and still having the caption shown even when the image is not focused.

```
    $('ul.rbt li').focus(function() {
        $('a').addClass('active');
           $('.caption').hide()
           $('.caption').show()
        });
    $('ul.rbt li').blur(function() {
        $('a').removeClass('active');
    });
```

Comment: unless this is not what you need, do tell

Comment: this would show the caption on the focused image and the caption would change to another image when another image is being focused on it

Comment: I'm not seeing that, it just shows all the captions for all images, no hide or show. I'll play around with the code and see if I can get it to work.